# Extensibility Framework for Angular

Tags: angularjs, web, mef, single-page-application

Is there anything like MEF for Angular?

Problem:  We have an n step wizard.  Based on some user criteria we would like certain steps to be different. It seems like we could treat these custom steps/experiences like extensions and have the corresponding modules loaded to drive that experience.

Then each custom experience would have a single responsibility.  The presentation, controller, business logic...etc would be simpler.

Or...is there another 'Angualr way' to achieve this.